# use of make depend while compiling fips enabled openssl

Tags: linux, compilation, openssl, makefile, solaris

I have solaris 10 machine. I'm trying to compile fips enabled openssl in it.

i was not able to build shared libraries using GNU gcc.

but with sun cc the build was successful. but sun cc doesnt have makedepend.

so is it safe to skip the make depend option while compiling?

what is the use of make depend in openssl ?

Answer (score 3):

makedepend is installed in `/usr/openwin/bin` on Solaris 10, if you've installed the X11 software - make sure that's in your $PATH if you installed it.   It's generally used by developers to insert into Makefiles information about which .o files depend on which .c & .h files, so that as they edit the software they can rebuild only the .o files that depend on the sources they edited.